# TypeError when trying to convert data into porcentaje

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I am working with a database that associates terms with 8 emotions and 2 sentiments. I have performed a first analysis on my corpus and added the results to a dataframe [df].

The ten new columns (8+2) contain data expressed in natural numbers. I would like to calculate the percentage and, to do so, I have used the following code:

```
emotions = ['Positive', 'Negative', 'Trust', 'Anger', 'Anticipation', 'Disgust', 'Fear','Sadness', 'Surprise', 'Joy']

for emotion in emotions:
    df[emotion] = df[emotion]/df['word_count']
```

I.e. the number in each column between the total number of words in each speech. The problem is that I get this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That error message isn't related to the code above... what it is saying is that somewhere in your code you are using `<` operator to compare a string and an int which are not comparable.

Comment: I have just corrected it. I had two columns with the same name, hence the problem. I thought it was because of the code, but no. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.